# Problem with vb to c# converter

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a method

```
 Public Property ConfigKeys(ByVal keyName As String) As WinItUtils.Classes.ConfigKey
            Get
                Return GetConfigKey(keyName)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As WinItUtils.Classes.ConfigKey)
                SetConfigKey(value)
            End Set
        End Property
```

and converter http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ gives me

```
public WinItUtils.Classes.ConfigKey ConfigKeys
        {
            get { return GetConfigKey(keyName); }
            set { SetConfigKey(value); }
        }
```

which is nonsense. Or maybe this is something that I don't know :/
I'm  newbie in visual basic, so maybe I'm missing something
I'm using .net 4.0

Here is the ConfigKey class:

```
Namespace Classes

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Business class that implements a configuration key from WINIT_CONFIG table.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Class ConfigKey
        Implements IEquatable(Of ConfigKey)

        Private _resourceKey As String

        Private _value As String

        Private _id As Integer

        Private _handlerId As Integer

        Private _configType As WinItUtils.Enums.WinItConfigTypes

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Property Id() As Integer
            Get
                Return _id
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _id = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property IsGlobal() As Boolean
            Get
                Return _handlerId < 0
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Property HandlerId() As Integer
            Get
                Return _handlerId
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _handlerId = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ResourceKey() As String
            Get
                Return _resourceKey
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _resourceKey = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ConfigType() As WinItUtils.Enums.WinItConfigTypes
            Get
                Return _configType
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As WinItUtils.Enums.WinItConfigTypes)
                _configType = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Value() As String
            Get
                Return _value
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _value = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
            Return Equals(TryCast(obj, ConfigKey))
        End Function

        Public Overloads Function Equals(ByVal other As ConfigKey) As Boolean _
        Implements IEquatable(Of ConfigKey).Equals
            If other Is Nothing Then
                Return False
            End If

            Return _handlerId = other.HandlerId And _resourceKey.Equals(other.ResourceKey) And _configType = other.ConfigType
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: See [Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: and [Parameterized Properties in C#](http://rbgupta.blogspot.com/2007/03/parameterized-properties-in-c.html)

Comment: There would normally be some hope with a little helper class that implements the indexer.  But that's idle hope with that setter, it doesn't take *keyname*.  You have no choice but to use methods.  Might as well expose Get/SetConfigKey() directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a method.

That is a *parameterized property*, which C# does not support.

There is no direct translation of your code into C#.
Instead, you should make a regular property that returns a `Dictionary<string, ConfigKey>`.

Comment: The main problem is whith parameter keyName in getter. I don't know how to deal with it

Comment: @user: Exactly.  That is a parameterized property, which C# does not support.