# VB.Net coding guidelines

Tags: .net, vb.net, coding-style, compiler-warnings

We develop small applications for various customers. I now got a task to set up some coding guidelines for in-house and external programmers.

(Management know nothing about development and only see the problem in transferring projects from one developer to another. Customers pay by the hour and development is a small part of total project so code quality is a non-issue)

My first step is to set up guidelines for C# and VB.Net (SQL will probably come later).

(Most code here is created with <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd><kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> and testing is done with <kbd>F5</kbd>.
I have tried to introduce unit testing / code review but that is not going to happen. Static analysis is the only way forward at the moment)

I am most comfortable in C#/C++ (but sometimes work with existing VB6/VBA/VB.Net code) so setting up C# guidelines is pretty easy:

- Warning Level 4
- StyleCop
- FxCop
- Code metrics (e.g. Cyclomatic complexity < 15, Maintainability > 50)

For VB.Net I need to replace StyleCop with some written guidelines but how do I set up the VB.Net compiler.
Personally I never code without `Option Explicit` / `Option Strict` etc but if I do that on our VB.Net projects I get hundreds of warnings/errors (implicit conversions, default return type/value etc).

The VB developers does not seem to have a problem working without help from compiler warnings. I do not think their productivity generally differs from C# developers (it is more a personal thing).

I do not want to enforce my own preference for static checking so my questions is:
**What warning levels are reasonable/best practice for VB.Net development?**

(English is not my first language so I hope this does not sound like I think VB.Net or VB Developers are inferior to C# in any way. I just don't have much experience in VB.Net projects)

Comment: http://addressof.com/blog/articles/CodingGuidelines.aspx

Comment: @CSharpVJ +1 for linking to coding guidelines which (it says) have had contributions from Paul Vick and Brad Abrams! But they date from 2005.

Answer (score 3):

VB.net is just equivalent to C#. If somebody has doubts about that he just can have a look to the various C# to VB.Net translators over the Internet. Chosing C# or VB.net is only a question of habits, readability and feeling. Not a technical or performance question.

Starting from this, almost the same guidelines you have stated for C# can be used for VB.net. So setting the same warnign level should be OK... (is there a possibility for VB.net too? I remember you have a set of options the compiler will warn you... )

The problem can be you will not have free tools like StyleCop (but there are commercial ones, like stated in [What StyleCop like tools are there for VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131350/what-stylecop-like-tools-are-there-for-vb-net) ).

You can also consider buying the Ultimate or Premium editions of Visual Studio (they have an integrated static analysis tool).

And YES, enforce use of Option Explicit / Option Strict (at least for new code or the one which s being reviewed!)

Comment: Would the downvoter please write a brief comment on why he/she downvoted? I'd really like to know if the answer is actually flawed or misleading. Or does the downvoter just generally dislike people stating that VB.Net is not a bad thing?

Comment: LOL, yes, I'm interested too in the reason for downvote... I hope it is not for religious issues :-)

Comment: +1 Minor quibbles. Vb.Net is 95% equivalent to C#, but [not *exactly* equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966457/what-is-allowed-in-visual-basic-thats-prohibited-in-c-sharp-or-vice-versa).

Comment: And the C# to VB.Net translators [all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148997/problem-with-vb-to-c-sharp-converter) [seem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212767/can-someone-help-me-convert-this-to-vb) to [fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201587/converting-inerface-with-delegate-from-vb-to-c-sharp) under [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566702/c-sharp-to-vb-class-event-sender-args-functionnameparams) [circumstances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279477/i-need-help-converting-a-c-sharp-anonymous-method-to-vb-net). I'm thinking of starting a tag :)